# People invited in a party - combinations

Tags: combinatorics

6 people are invited in a party. Any two of them, either love each other or hate each other.
There is no set of 3 guests (out of these 6) for which any two love each other.
Prove that there exists at least one set of 3 guests for which any two hate each other.

All possible ways to love/hate each other are 15. Then what??

Comment: This is just the [friends and stranger's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem_on_friends_and_strangers) which is a specific case of [Ramsey's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem).  One can prove that in a two-colored complete graph on six vertices there must exist a monochromatic triangle.  If the monochromatic triangle guaranteed is not specifically for them all loving eachother, then it must be that there is a monochromatic triangle where they all hate eachother.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose it is not true.

Suppose there exist someone $A$ who hates at least 3 people. Since we have no love triangle two of those three must hate each other. So we have hate triangle.

Now suppose each hates at most 2 people. So every one loves at least three people. Look again at $A$. Then every two of his friends must hate each other since there is no love triangle.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it with linear algebra.

1. Let 1 denote "loves".
2. Then assume a binary matrix with position $i,j$ encoding the truthness of "$i$ loves $j$".
3. Set up equations for each 3x3 block for a vectorization of the matrix.
4. Then solve the equation system.

Comment: If you really think this novel method is a good way to attack this classic problem please provide the details. After all, the combinatorial solution is quite well known.

Comment: I did not say I thought it would be good. It's probably quite horrible. But you don't learn as much only doing the good solutions.

Comment: I agree that you can often learn from new methods. So show us this one.

Comment: Maybe I can expand on it some day after work. If I find the time.